# prisma error: Cannot select both '$scalars: true' and a specific scalar field 'accountCompanies'

Tags: node.js, prisma

I cannot solve this error. Any help?

Cannot select both '$scalars: true' and a specific scalar field 'accountCompanies'.

```
model Account {
  id String  @id @default(cuid())
  avatar String?
  lastName String
  firstName String

  accountCompanies AccountCompany[]
}

model Company {
  id String  @id @default(cuid())
  name String

  accountCompanies AccountCompany[]
}

model AccountCompany {
  account Account @relation(fields: [accountId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  accountId String
  company Company @relation(fields: [companyId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
  companyId String
  role Role  @default(GENERAL)

  @@id(fields: [accountId, companyId])
}
```

The above error occurs in the code below.

```
  const account = await prisma.account.findUnique({
    where: { auth0UserId: auth0User.sub },
    include: { accountCompanies: true },
  });
```

Comment: I can't see a auth0UserId column in your account model which you seem to be using in the query. Is it intentional?

Comment: in my case the issue was coming from the include, double check if `accountCompanies` is the name of your actual table?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same error, was able to clear it by restarting the TypeScript & Prism language servers in VSCode, and restarting the web server. That seems to be the recommended approach for resolving weird Prisma issues.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else searching this same error message, as this was basically the only page I found for it.

I had this issue due to a capitalization bug. I meant to be referencing a relationship using 'Products' with a capital 'P', but I had accidentally written  'products' with a lower case 'p' in both the 'create' and 'include' section of the Prisma query.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when I was referencing to the wrong table which didnt have the said relation.

Just posting it here for future if you landed here, please check you are referencing the right table.